# How to handle Android LiveData(ViewModel) with ProgressBar on screen rotate?

Tags: android, viewmodel, progressdialog

`onChanged` I am updating the UI and cancelling the `progressDialog` but each time I am rotating the screen the progress dialog shows up and **ProgressDialog doesn't dismiss**.

**How to handle the progressdialog if the data is not changed?**

```
 final ProgressDialog pd;
    pd=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    pd.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.updating));
    pd.show();MutableLiveData<BillGetResponse> DisplayByIdLiveData=viewModelForBillDisplay.getBillGetResponseDisplayById(txnRequest);

    if (display_by_id) {


        DisplayByIdLiveData.observe(BillDisplayFragment.this, new Observer<BillGetResponse>() {


            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable BillGetResponse billGetResponse) {


                if (btnRecordDisableEnabled != null)
                    btnRecordDisableEnabled.enable();

                pd.dismiss();  }
```

but everytime the `onChanged` is not trigerred and the progressdialog doesnot stop !!

Comment: post code where you are displaying ProgressDialog and hiding it

Comment: Have updated the answer ...dont mind the edit please @Akhil

Comment: 1st time the *dialog dismissed correctly** but as the screen rotates the dialog keeps coming ... (as `onChanged` is called only once)..

Answer (score 10):

You need other observer to handle the value of the boolean that indicates if you have to show the ProgressDialog or not. This is the code:

```
viewModel.getIsLoading().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
            if(aBoolean){
                pd.show();
            }else{
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

In your viewModel add getIsLoading method:

```
public LiveData<Boolean> getIsLoading(){
    LiveData<Boolean> isLoading=yourRepository.getIsLoading();
    return isLoading;
}
```

And in your repository add:

```
private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> isLoading=new MutableLiveData<>();
```

and set value to isLoading when start and finish the data upload.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`onChanged()` not getting called is perfectly normal, it means there are no more changes in data.

I guess you want to show **ProgressDialog** while data is being fetched or loaded. You can do something like this

In `onCreate()` Check data is present or not before displaying, below in Pseudo code for displaying **ProgressDialog**

```
if (!hasData())
   displayProgressDialog()
```

**EDIT**:
It seems you want to inform user that data has changed by means of showing ProgressDialog, You can achieve this by showing this for small moment and dismiss it after a while, Something like this in `onChanged()`

```
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable BillGetResponse billGetResponse) {
        if (btnRecordDisableEnabled != null)
            btnRecordDisableEnabled.enable();

        displayProgressDialog(); //Show progress dialog here
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pd.dismiss();   
            }
        },500);
    }
```

Comment: I have used fragment and the fragment is reused **Once the data is loaded hasData() is always true** 2nd time if the fragment loads dialog wont show...

Comment: Did u get my point ?? **2nd time if the data is different `onChanged`** will be called but progress wont show before..

Comment: Its showing a blank screen if the data is changed and after the response comes and data is loaded the progress dialog shows for some time...

Comment: i just want to avoid the user from seeing the blank screen...before any data loads...

Comment: You should use first code snippet in your onCreate as well... i.e. if no data then show ProgressDialog in onCreate also